# Hide Picturebox if image is invalid

Tags: vb.net, image, telerik, report, picturebox

I am creating reports using Telerik Reporting Tool and has some image on it. I display the Image in the picturebox using a URL that came from the clients but there are instances where the given URL is invalid so it will display an error message in the report. I want to just hide the picturebox whenever the Image is not available so that the error will not appear in the report. how can I do it? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a webrequest on your website.
For example:

```
Public Sub Run()
    Dim myReportImage As Image = GetControl("ReportImage")
    myReportImage.Visible = CheckWebImage()
    ' or
    myReportImage.Enabled = CheckWebImage()
End Sub

Private Function CheckWebImage() As Boolean
    Dim url As New System.Uri("http://www.url.com/yourImage.jpg")
    Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse

    Try
        response = req.GetResponse()
        response.Close()
        request = Nothing
        Msgbox("Website Found!")
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        request = Nothing
        Msgbox("Website not found. Check the url and internet connection")
        Return False
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I got an error, it says: **Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.** what does that mean?

Comment: Could you give as an expample for your url?

Comment: It's already Working! your given code is absolutely working, maybe I just had some problems with the sequence of object events yesterday, but I already fixed it. THANK YOU SO MUCH for your help! it really helped me a lot :D